# How is this a segment fault 11? Only 5x200 entry arrays

Tags: c, macos, segmentation-fault

I'm working on Mac OSX, and using bash in terminal. The machine has 8GB of RAM. I don't know why I am getting a segment fault 11 for this code. From my three weeks of experience, I usually get them form having too much memory being requested. But I am only asking for 5, 200 entry arrays. Does this have something to do with opening and reading text files?

What could to make the program run, as is? Is malloc relevant to this? Thanks for any help you can offer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
double Mj[200]={0};
double Ma[200]={0};
double Cj[200]={0};
double Ca[200]={0};
double index[200]={0};

FILE *Matlab;
Matlab = fopen("TestbedComp.txt","r");
FILE *Cprog;
Cprog = fopen("results.txt","r");

int j = 0;
while( fscanf(Matlab,"%lf, %lf, %lf", &index[j], &Mj[j], &Ma[j]) == 3 ){
    printf("%lf, %lf, %lf\n", index[j], Mj[j], Ma[j]);
    j++;
}

fclose(Matlab);
printf("\n");

j = 0;
while( fscanf(Cprog,"%lf, %lf, %lf", &index[j], &Cj[j], &Ca[j]) == 3 ){
    printf("%lf, %lf, %lf\n", index[j], Cj[j], Ca[j]);
    j++;
}

fclose(Cprog);

double pej[200]={0};
for (j=0; j<200; j++) {
    pej[j] = fabs(Mj[j]-Cj[j])/Mj[j];
}

double pea[200]={0};
for (j=0; j<200; j++) {
    pea[j] = fabs(Ma[j]-Ca[j])/Ma[j];
}

FILE *out;
out = fopen("PercentError.txt","w");

for (j=0; j<200; j++) {
    fprintf(out,"%.15lf, %.15lf, %.15lf \n", index[j], pej[j], pea[j]);
}

fclose(out);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line? What is the error message?

Comment: Sorry, I get "Segmentation fault: 11" while it is running the first while loop.

Comment: How many lines is it scanning in? Segfault is often caused by accessing an array index out of bounds. If I remember correctly.

Comment: You have almost no error checking.  You do not check the return value of fopen, you do not check that j is not bigger than 199 in the fscanf loop.  That's a recipe for disaster

Comment: Boy do I feel like an idiot. Thanks to both @iamnotmaynard and Guilaume. The file has more than 200 lines...

Comment: @NoviceC - Please don't edit with "resolved" that's not how StackOverflow works. Pick the answer that best answered your questions instead and "accept" it, that will mark it as resolved to the world. If it was a comment that answered your question then ask the author to make it an answer so you can accept it, or you could always do it yourself as a community-wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fscanf`reads until the end of line. If there's no lines in the code it will try to read it completely, and you can run into segmentation fault.

Can you provide examples of the files you're trying to read?

Answer (score 1):

I bet you are really crashing in the function preamble... 1000 doubles is taking 16000 bytes  off of your stack right away. try `calloc`ing those instead of using stack allocations.